# Associated models without nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models:

```
class GarageOwner < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :garages, dependent: :destroy
end

class Garage < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :garage_owner
end
```

A Garage should never exist without a garage owner. So in the `new` action of the `GaragesController` I need the corresponding garage owner. I do not want to use nested routes so I do not have the garage owners id as a parameter. But how do I get him then?

**Update for some clarification**

Garages are created by a third model (`Admin`). So I can not access the garage owner through the current user.

I build my routes using `resources`:

```
       garage_owners GET    /garage_owners(.:format)          garage_owners#index
                     POST   /garage_owners(.:format)          garage_owners#create
    new_garage_owner GET    /garage_owners/new(.:format)      garage_owners#new
   edit_garage_owner GET    /garage_owners/:id/edit(.:format) garage_owners#edit
        garage_owner GET    /garage_owners/:id(.:format)      garage_owners#show
                     PUT    /garage_owners/:id(.:format)      garage_owners#update
                     DELETE /garage_owners/:id(.:format)      garage_owners#destroy
             garages GET    /garages(.:format)                garages#index
                     POST   /garages(.:format)                garages#create
          new_garage GET    /garages/new(.:format)            garages#new
         edit_garage GET    /garages/:id/edit(.:format)       garages#edit
              garage GET    /garages/:id(.:format)            garages#show
                     PUT    /garages/:id(.:format)            garages#update
                     DELETE /garages/:id(.:format)            garages#destroy
```

Comment: You should pass it as a parameter. How do your routes look like?
BTW why don't you want to use nested routes?

Comment: I do not want to "garage_owner" to show up in my URLs. I updated the question. You can see the routes there.

Comment: where goes the `garage_owner` come from? it's not in the URL, it's not to do with an associated user, how does anyone or the application know which the `garage_owner` is?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found an appropriate solution which is still restful I think. I just created multiple routes for garages:

```
resources :garage_owners do
  resources :garages, except: :index
end

resources :garages, only: [:index, :show]
```

Normal users should not access the other actions.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to not using nested routes is to insert the `garage_owner_id` as a hidden field in your new garage form. But, you've given no indication in your question of how the new garage form is meant to know about which `garage_owner` it should associate with so I can't give you a specific example.

Comment: Well that is the problem. I don't know how the form should know about it :P

I think I have to choose between a custom route or nested routes even if it looks not that good.

Comment: I'm not worried about how the form should know about it, that can be resolved by passing it in some how. But how does ANYTHING know about it? Is the information stored in the person's brain who's looking at the "new garage" form? Rails can't help you there..

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this a couple different ways:

1. If the `GarageOwer` requires a login, you could grab the ID of the `GarageOwer` user from the cookie stored at login.
2. Create a custom route `match "/Garages/new/:owner_id" => "garages#new"`, there after in your controller access the owner's id via `params[:owner_id]`.
3. Add `owner_id` as a hidden attributed to the form on the "garages/new" page.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes says that this is not a resourceful route. Is this bad?

Comment: @feuerball It's not the end of the world.  If you are really interesting in restful routes though, make the Garage routes nested...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm not getting your question, but I think you'd have to either pick up the garage owner from your session (e.g. logged in user), or something derived from a value in your session or as a value submitted with the form used for the new operation, in which case it would be a parameter.